# set back the focus in GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt, focus

I have four text boxes and one ListBox placed in a FlexTable. I make a request to server to get the list of data to populate the ListBox. 
When the response comes back, I populate the ListBox. This is stealing focus from the TextBox where I am giving input.

What I want is after populating the ListBox, return the focus back to the exact location where it was before.

How to do it in GWT or even in java script?

Comment: Do you want this to be a generic solution (you don't know which widget had the focus before) or are you keeping track of your widgets and know which one should have the focus? The later is obviously much easier and boils down to calling `setFocus` (provided that the Widget implements the [`Focusable`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Focusable.html) interface).

Comment: I need first one since I don't know in which TextBox user might be typing when response comes back.

Answer (score 1):

If You need generic solution, create class, that implements BlurHandler or FocusHandler interface. Assign object of this class to your text boxes. In onFocus/onBlur method just remember last focused widget.
After populating of ListBox just call something like restoreFocus() which will call setFocus(true) on that remebered object.

Comment: Nice idea, it will work for me (though I still has to check if the cursor position returns exactly to the same character in the text box) since I only have 2 or 3 text boxes; but how everybody is handling this scenario (it seems un-avoidable in AJAX apps)?